# connectivity error vbscript sqlserver?

Tags: sql-server, vbscript, connection-string, oledb, adodb

```
<%@ language="vbscript" %>
<html>
<body>
<P>
<%

dim adOpenDynamic,adLockOptimistic,adCmdtext

adOpenDynamic=0

adLockoptimistic=1

adCmdtext=2
dim i
i=1
dim conn,rs,strsql
dim fname,lname,gender,month,date,year,uname,pwd,email


set conn=Server.Createobject("ADODB.Connection")
set rs=Server.Createobject("ADODB.Recordset")

conn.ConnectionString="Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=myshoppe;Data Source=NVC-10\SQLEXPRESS"

conn.Open

fname=Request.Form("first_name")
lname=Request.Form("last_name")
gender=Request.Form("gender")
'month=Request.Form("Month")
'date=Request.Form("date")
'year=Request.Form("year")
email=Request.Form("email")
uname=Request.Form("user_name")
pwd=Request.Form("pwd")

strsql = "INSERT INTO user_info(fname, lname, gender, email, uname, pwd) VALUES(' " & fname & "',' " & lname &"',' " & gender & "',  "& email & "',' " & uname & "',' " & pwd & "')"                                                                

conn.Execute (strsql)
Response.Write("submitted<>")

Response.Write "Connected OK"


%>
<br>


</P>

</body>
</html>
```

> Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL
>   Server (0x80040E09) INSERT permission
>   denied on object 'user_info', database
>   'myshoppe', schema 'dbo'.

Comment: `Integrated Security=SSPI` will mean that your script may be running as either ASPNET, IIS_IUSR or IIS_WPG user. Check to see if the user has correct privileges in SQL Server. Otherwise, if it's the wrong user, you may choose to change the user your ASP is run after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an opening single quote before your email variable.

Comment: i got that error bt after that i got another error. i edited my question

Comment: The user you are using to connect to the database does not have permission to insert.  You need to get that user more access to the database.